# Помогите сравнить 2 массива объектов и заменить значения

Tags: javascript, массивы, объекты

есть 2 массива объектов:

```
arr1 = [
          {name: 'Bohdan', id: 1, totalSpendings: 0, finalSpendings: 0},
          {name: 'Kate', id: 2, totalSpendings: 0, finalSpendings: 0},
          {name: 'Victor', id: 3, totalSpendings: 0, finalSpendings: 0},
          {name: 'Lara', id:4, totalSpendings: 0, finalSpendings: 0}
      ]
arr2 = [{name: "Bohdan", totalSpendings: "1"}, 
{name: "Kate", totalSpendings: "2"}, 
{name: "Victor", totalSpendings: "3"},
{name: "Lara", totalSpendings: "4"}]
```

нужно сравнить обьекты по значению name, и если они одинаковы - тогда заменить значение  finalSpendings с первого обьекта на значение со второго

Comment: ну хоть покажи, как пытался это сделать )

Comment: finalSpendings нету во втором масиве обьектов, может ты ошибся в описании проблемы ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В силу того что задание ты написал немного не понятно, даю такой код:

```js
arr1.forEach((e, ind) => {
    if (e.name !== arr2[ind].name) return;
    e.totalSpendings = +arr2[ind].totalSpendings;
})
// для теста результата
console.log(arr1)
```

если оно присваивает не так что либо что тебе нужно - отпиши в коменты